# Laravel passport API retrieve access_token to check if really exist on database

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.5

I'm using laravel passport and axios, I want to check if the current access token of authenticated user is really inside my database so what I did

Auth.js. On this function I don't just want to check if there's token in localStorage but also to check if its really inside the database.

```
isAuthenticated(){
    if(this.getToken()){
        //get access_token
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: '/prod/api/authcheck',
            data: {},
            config : 'JSON'
        })
        .then(response=>{

        })
        .catch(response=>{

    });
        return true
    }else{
        return false
    }
 }
```

route

```
Route::get('/authcheck', 'HelperController@checkAuth')->name('authcheck');
```

HelperController.php.

```
public function checkAuth(Request $request){
    $user_id = $request->user();
    print_r($request->user());
}
```

In this part when I try to `print_r($request->user())` it gives me this output

```
App\User Object
(
    [fillable:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => name
            [1] => email
            [2] => password
        )

    [hidden:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => password
            [1] => remember_token
        )

    [connection:protected] => mysql
    [table:protected] => 
    [primaryKey:protected] => id
    [keyType:protected] => int
    [incrementing] => 1
    [with:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [withCount:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [perPage:protected] => 15
    [exists] => 1
    [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
    [attributes:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => biansor
            [email] => bs@gmail.com
            [password] => $2y$10$KPCD4Vbgqqaxxcqa8bNpQ.UDBfkETO4Krf9dFEMKd4.uN8c0qTD52
            [remember_token] => T8nVWkJMaO6fr51rqu6HWzdtUri3c9nK9bdsSqSTSBQ7xD1qXNN1taPQWBlZ
            [created_at] => 
            [updated_at] => 2017-11-19 15:31:24
        )

    [original:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => biansor
            [email] => bs@gmail.com
            [password] => $2y$10$KPCD4Vbgqqaxxcqa8bNpQ.UDBfkETO4Krf9dFEMKd4.uN8c0qTD52
            [remember_token] => T8nVWkJMaO6fr51rqu6HWzdtUri3c9nK9bdsSqSTSBQ7xD1qXNN1taPQWBlZ
            [created_at] => 
            [updated_at] => 2017-11-19 15:31:24
        )

    [changes:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [casts:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dates:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dateFormat:protected] => 
    [appends:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [observables:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [relations:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [touches:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [timestamps] => 1
    [visible:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [guarded:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => *
        )

    [rememberTokenName:protected] => remember_token
    [accessToken:protected] => Laravel\Passport\Token Object
        (
            [table:protected] => oauth_access_tokens
            [incrementing] => 
            [guarded:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [casts:protected] => Array
                (
                    [scopes] => array
                    [revoked] => bool
                )

            [dates:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => expires_at
                )

            [timestamps] => 
            [connection:protected] => mysql
            [primaryKey:protected] => id
            [keyType:protected] => int
            [with:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [withCount:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [perPage:protected] => 15
            [exists] => 1
            [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
            [attributes:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => bd38c210ae36780ff4165f7ae468d156c9ebb24c2c5fe30c5ac40c49c1a2bc4d9396b9518934244b
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [client_id] => 2
                    [name] => 
                    [scopes] => []
                    [revoked] => 0
                    [created_at] => 2017-11-21 14:10:22
                    [updated_at] => 2017-11-21 14:10:22
                    [expires_at] => 2018-11-21 14:10:22
                )

            [original:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => bd38c210ae36780ff4165f7ae468d156c9ebb24c2c5fe30c5ac40c49c1a2bc4d9396b9518934244b
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [client_id] => 2
                    [name] => 
                    [scopes] => []
                    [revoked] => 0
                    [created_at] => 2017-11-21 14:10:22
                    [updated_at] => 2017-11-21 14:10:22
                    [expires_at] => 2018-11-21 14:10:22
                )

            [changes:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [dateFormat:protected] => 
            [appends:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [observables:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [relations:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [touches:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [hidden:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [visible:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [fillable:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

So now this is what I need, how can I retrieve either one of this part? So that I can get the access_token [id]

```
[attributes:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => bd38c210ae36780ff4165f7ae468d156c9ebb24c2c5fe30c5ac40c49c1a2bc4d9396b9518934244b
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [client_id] => 2
                    [name] => 
                    [scopes] => []
                    [revoked] => 0
                    [created_at] => 2017-11-21 14:10:22
                    [updated_at] => 2017-11-21 14:10:22
                    [expires_at] => 2018-11-21 14:10:22
                )

            [original:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => bd38c210ae36780ff4165f7ae468d156c9ebb24c2c5fe30c5ac40c49c1a2bc4d9396b9518934244b
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [client_id] => 2
                    [name] => 
                    [scopes] => []
                    [revoked] => 0
                    [created_at] => 2017-11-21 14:10:22
                    [updated_at] => 2017-11-21 14:10:22
                    [expires_at] => 2018-11-21 14:10:22
                )
```

If I just do the return `response()->json($request->user())` it just give me the table of user created_at, email, id, name, updated_at.

AccessToken model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AccessToken extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'oauth_access_token';

    public function refresh_token(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\RefreshToken', 'id', 'access_token_id');
    }


    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: try `$request->user()['accessToken'];`

Comment: @Rits No display sir

Comment: in your user model token is protected right? might be the issue is there.

Comment: are you retrieving token data by relation ??

Comment: @Rits Not for this moment because really important is to get those access_token. But why if I print_r the $request->user() it gives me the whole output can't find the way to retrieve those 2 part.

Comment: can we see you user model plz?

Comment: @Rits I updated the question

Comment: and where is your user model?

Comment: we need to see user model cos you are querying on user model.

Comment: I pretty sure I can handle that once I got the access_token I got my plan B I review the process flow if I changed the access_token in localstorage it will response as unauthorized user so by that I can do something to destroy that token.

Comment: hm you can retrieve all that data in your view also like, `auth()->user()`
or `$request->user()` in your controller.

Comment: I've got the same idea, wonder why this was never replied. As far as I can see this localStorage token is not the same as anything in the database, so the simplest thing is to send any simple request to the backend using these credentials and it will return you a 401 error.